# Which usage of singleton is the most proper/pythonic?

Tags: python, singleton

I am wondering which way is the best, most proper or the most pythonic to call a singleton variable.

Here is my singleton code:

```
class SingletonMeta(type):
    _instances = {}

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls not in cls._instances:
            instance = super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)
            cls._instances[cls] = instance
        return cls._instances[cls]


class Singleton(metaclass=SingletonMeta):
    @classmethod
    def set_value(cls, key, value):
        setattr(cls, key, value)

        return value

    @classmethod
    def get_value(cls, key):
        return getattr(cls, key)
```

And my first approach looked like this:

```
Singleton.set_value('my_value', True)
print(Singleton.get_value('my_value'))
```

But it looked kinda "ugly" for me.

So I changed `Singleton` class to simply `pass` and then I could just do:

```
Singleton.my_value = True
print(Singleton.my_value)
```

And to calm PyCharm down I am adding to `Singleton` class `my_value = None`.

I am wondering, which approach from those is the best? Or maybe I should to it in different way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second way is best, but ...

The SingletonMeta you've created does what you want it to do in the sense that it ensures that you can't create more than one instance of the Singleton class. It does this by ensuring that each time that `Singleton()` is called the same instance is returned. So

```
>>> a = Singleton()
>>> b = Singleton()
>>> a is b
True
```

Having gone to that trouble, this now works:

```
>>> a.my_value = True
>>> b.my_value
True
```

The fact that you can create the attributes as easily on the class as on the instance is very much par for the course in Python. If you create an attribute on the class it is 'shared' by all instances, if you create it on an instance it's particular to that instance. Since there is one and only one instance of a Singleton, it is not clear why you would then want to create/change attributes of the Singleton class itself, rather than the instance. Arguably, the most Pythonic way would be to assign value to attributes on the instance `Singleton()`, rather than `Singleton` itself

Comment: Hmm, I didn't think about this. So you are saying that everywhere where I want to access data in my singleton I should do something like `my_singleton = Singleton()` and then `my_singleton.my_value = True` and I should do that in each class that I want to access this `my_value` is that correct? Because in that way I would be using everywhere an instance, and not class itself, right?

Comment: It depends on your particular use case for the singleton pattern. The SingletonMeta you have shown is one of many possible implementations of the Singleton pattern . You would use this particular implementationto to hide the fact that different instances of your Singleton class are in fact the same object. That only makes sense if you have different instances. If you just want to change the attributes of a global object, create that global object. No need to use (instances of) a singleton metaclass for that.

Comment: My use case is storing "settings" for my app. I have many classes and modules in my program and I needed a way to dynamically react to different settings changing in different places and moments. That is why I decided on the singleton. Currently I am wondering if going with just `Singleton.my_value = True` instead of `my_singleton = Singleton()` and `my_singleton.my_value = True` will be considered a mistake?

Comment: Settings are by their nature global, so it is ok to put the settings in a global variable in a settings module. Even though you import that module in different parts of your program it will always be the same module and, hence, the same global objects in its namespace. Exacltly the kind of singleton-behaviour you are looking for,

Comment: Thank you. I did one more small change and I just did it like that - `Settings().my_value = True`. What do you think about approach like that? I think it's also good because I am actually using Singleton here (and not class variable) and I don't need to create one class instance and the beginning of code because I can just go with `Settings()` everywhere because I am using Singleton. What do you think?